# Jquery onclick scrolltop speed not changing/delays the animation instead

Tags: jquery, onclick, scrolltop

I have function that scrolls the page back to the top when clicked:

```
$('.back-to-top').on('click', function(){
        $("html").animate({ scrollTop: 0 },300);
    });
```

The function is working correctly but for some unknown reason, the speed variable (300) does not change the speed but delays the animation instead.

I don't see any speed change when I set it to $("html").animate({ scrollTop: 0 },0); versus $("html").animate({ scrollTop: 0 },300), and $("html").animate({ scrollTop: 0 },3000) significantly slowed down the animation,,,

Does anyone know the issue? Thank you!

Comment: Can you please add all relevant code which demonstrates the issue to your question. In isolation, this works fine, and the scroll is reset to the top immediately when using `0` delay - although doing that makes the animation redundant: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/5Lroetsn/

Comment: The complete js file is way too big so I will just paste the relevant blocks. Here are the two functions that I called:

    //scrollbar scroll down on click
    $('.scrollbar').on('click', function(){
            $("html").animate({ scrollTop: 600 },300);
        });


    //scrollbar scroll back to top on click
    $('.back-to-top').on('click', function(){
            $("html").animate({ scrollTop: 0 },300);
        });

Both of them are wrapped under a $(window).on('load', function(){}

Comment: Also, there seems to be a slight delay after clicking on the div element before the scrolling animation happens